# Check Leiningen Template Version Number

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Trying out a new `leiningen` template. After running the template command, 
the dependencies + `project.clj` built as expected.

```
lein new template-name project-name
```

However, `lein run` to start the web server threw a `No such namespace error`, even though the `project.clj` had the `:main namespace.name` correctly defined, so far as I can tell.

The template was not a project dependency, so it was not immediately obvious to me if the template was broken or some sort of path issue on my end.

I think I fixed my bug deleting the project and rebuilding with the `lein -U` update flag, but am still curious how to check the template version number.

How can I check the version number of the template that `lein new` is running?

I looked in `lein help new` and found how to specify a version but not how to check the one being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leiningen templates are installed in your `.m2` directory. So you could just `cd ~/.m2/repository/template-name`. There you should see directories named by the versions you have installed.